# Did Kirk kill this feline dancer?

Tags: star-trek, the-final-frontier

In *Star Trek V: The Final Frontier*, James T. Kirk enters the bar in Paradise City on Nimbus III, he is jumped upon by the [unnamed feline "exotic dancer"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nimbus_III_feline_dancer_001#Exotic_dancer_001) seen in an earlier scene. As Memory Alpha notes, Kirk

> ... neutralized her attack by throwing her into a water pool table.

Memory Alpha continues:

> It is later indicated, as [the dancer] floats in the water, that she was unconscious.

From my memory, she is floating upside-down in the water, and is never seen in the film again. If she was unconscious and face-down in water, wouldn't she drown? Doesn't this mean that Kirk has (albeit not directly) killed her (despite usually avoiding killing needlessly)?

Comment: Not only from your memory - she _is_ floating upside-down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Inconclusive, but unlikely

Your memory is indeed correct. This dancer did land face-down in the water. I have found footage from the fight on Youtube:

At the end of the landing, you can see her landing with her posterior aimed upwards, and after Spock enters, you can see the back of her hands, as well as her heels.

However, only moments after Spock entered, Kirk and Spock are met with partners of the feline dancer, so it's fair to assume she was rescued from the water by one of them. This isn't shown in the video though.

Answer (score 25):

The [script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Trek/Star_Trek_V.htm) says that she was merely *unconscious*

> Spock enters and reacts  to the unconscious Catwoman as Kirk blasts
>   open the door to the back room. Caithlin, Korrd and Talbot look up  in
>   surprise. Kirk breathes a sigh of relief.

and the [official novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_V:_The_Final_Frontier_(novel)) notes that she was (latterly) *floating face upwards*

> "Spock," Jim said. He stepped forward out of the shadows, gasping and
>   rearranging his cloak. At the same instant Spock noticed **an
>   unconscious felinoid floating face up in a shallow gaming pool**. Water had sloshed
>   onto the dusty floor and the front of Jim's cloak, leaving a dark
>   stain.

### Given that there were other patrons who weren't knocked out, I think we can assume that she got fished out off-screen later, alive and well.

Comment: Assuming that others will help is the start of many fatalities. :/

Comment: Presumably someone flipped her over while still unconscious, so she at least wouldn't drown. Nice retcon...

Comment: @Valorum the script says she is unconscious at that moment, it says nothing about her future.  The future of someone floating face down and unconscious is drown unless removed from the water soon.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - The script says face down but a few seconds later her colleagues re-enter the room. The novelisation is more upbeat, stating that she turns face up. Either way we can reasonably assume that she wasn't left to drown by her co-workers